# In one class I run two test, one pass other failed, but I know that selector is correct

Tags: automated-tests, testng

PASSED: parentLoginPageTest
FAILED: parentLogoutTest
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"#root > div > div > div > div > form > div.form-group.mx-auto.mt-3 > div > input"}
(Session info: chrome=88.0.4324.190)
For documentation on this error, please visit: https://www.seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'

public class ParentPageTest extends BaseTest{

```
@Test
public void parentLoginPageTest () throws InterruptedException {
    MainParentPage parentPage = new MainParentPage(driver);
    
    parentPage.doParentLogin();
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    
    //paimam teksta, tikrinam ar prisijungimas sekmingas
    String actualLoginText = parentPage.textSuccessfulParentLogin();
    String expectedLoginText = "Vaiko atstovas";
    assertEquals(expectedLoginText, actualLoginText);
    }


@Test
public void parentLogoutTest () throws InterruptedException {
    MainParentPage parentPage = new MainParentPage(driver);
    
    parentPage.doParentLogin();
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    parentPage.doParentLogout();

    String actualLogoutText = parentPage.textSuccessfulParentLogout();
    String expectedLogoutText = "Prisijungimo vardas";
    assertEquals(expectedLogoutText, actualLogoutText);
    
}
```

}

Comment: Yes, it is correct, how I can to solve this ? I need one test for login, ant other for logout

Comment: Turned my comment into answer, so others may also better find it.

Answer (score 0):

It is totally possible to be an issue with how you handle the browser instance and/or the test flow. From the stack trace you've posted

```
div.form-group.mx-auto.mt-3 > div > input
```

is most likely related to the `parentPage.doParentLogin();` attempted for a second time without actually being on the login page. So, in order to solve this, as you seem to test two things - just split your flow into `login` and `logout` tests. It would be wise to utilise an `@AfterEach` method which is executed after each test method. Used to cleanup the test environment, e.g., close browser instances, delete temporary data, restore defaults, cleanup expensive memory structures.